# Согласование падежей в предложении

Tags: падежи

"он выбрал себе книгу попроще, типа «Сценарного мастерства для чайников»"
или "он выбрал себе книгу попроще, типа "Сценарное мастерство для чайников"?

мне кажется, что второй вариант правильный, но обосновать не могу. Надеюсь на помощь сайта. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Основное значение слова ***тип*** определяется по словарю (существительное и предлог);

ТИП, -а; м. [греч. týpos - отпечаток, форма, образец] 1. Образец, модель или разновидность, форма, которым соответствует известная группа предметов, явлений. **Разные типы колясок**. Устаревший т. автомобиля.<Типа, в зн. предлога. Вроде, наподобие. **Гостиница типа пансионата.**

Предлог участвует **в управлении Р.п.**

2) В этом случае предложение звучит так: ***Он выбирал (хотел выбрать) себе книгу попроще, типа «Сценарного мастерства для чайников».***

При отсутствии родового наименования (учебное пособие) название книги по правилам ставится в форму Р.п.

2) Но слово ***типа*** в современном  языке приобрело **сленговое значение междометия или частицы**, и в этом случае возможен **И.п. (всё зависит от стиля текста):** ***Он выбирал (хотел выбрать) себе книгу попроще, типа «Сценарное мастерство для чайников»***

Можно заменить: *Он выбирал (хотел выбрать) себе книгу попроще, **например**  «Сценарное мастерство для чайников».*

Статьи о слове ***типа***:

http://ozhegov.textologia.ru/definit/tipa/?q=742&n=206121

http://www.aif.ru/society/education/tipa_ili_tipo_-_kak_pravilno

Answer (score 0):

Правилен первый вариант. Никто не отменял согласование в падеже. *Вы читали "Войну и мир"? Что вам больше всего понравилось в "Парне из преисподней"?*

Другое дело, что во фразе логическая нестыковка. Он выбрал определенную книгу, к чему тогда этот "неопределенный артикль" *типа*?

Comment: "Другое дело, что во фразе логическая нестыковка. Он выбрал определенную книгу, к чему тогда этот "неопределенный артикль" типа?" - речь идет как раз о типе книг-самоучителей, "Что-то там для чайников". Так что как раз "туалет типа сортир" здесь присутствует

Answer (score 0):

Правилен первый вариант: для проверки замените "типа" на "**вроде**". Дело в том, что в буквальном смысле "тип книги" (ср. "туалет типа *сортир*") здесь не фигурирует.

Answer (score 0):

**"он выбрал себе книгу попроще, типа «Сценарного мастерства для чайников»" или "он выбрал себе книгу попроще, типа "Сценарное мастерство для чайников"?**
Мне кажется вы мухлюете с запятой.
1) Он выбрал себе книгу попроще типа «Сценарного мастерства для чайников»" (тогда и "типа" можно убрать);
2) Он выбрал себе книгу попроще, типа "Сценарное мастерство для чайников"

Comment: *Мне кажется вы мухлюете с запятой.* — А Вы здесь не "мухлюете" с запятой? (На этом я решил прочтение такого ответа завершить.)